# How to get video attributes in iOS8 share extension

Tags: ios, video, share, ios8, ios-app-extension

I am trying to create a sharing extension to share videos using the new iOS 8 app extensions.I want to open the photo app and share the video by my extension.

I get the video url by following codes:

```
NSExtensionItem *inputItem = self.extensionContext.inputItems.firstObject;
    NSItemProvider *provider = inputItem.attachments[0];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT,0), ^{

        if ([provider hasItemConformingToTypeIdentifier:(NSString *)kUTTypeQuickTimeMovie])
        {
            [provider loadItemForTypeIdentifier:@"com.apple.quicktime-movie" options:nil completionHandler:^(NSURL *path,NSError *error){
                if (path)
                {
                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                        _moviePath = path;
                    });
                }
            }];
        }
    });
```

But I only got the video file url:

```
file:///var/mobile/Media/DCIM/100APPLE/IMG_0062.MOV
```

I also want to get more video attributes ,like: size and duration

I used following codes,but not work:

```
NSDictionary *opts = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO]                                                   forKey:AVURLAssetPreferPreciseDurationAndTimingKey];
 AVURLAsset *urlAsset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:_moviePath options:opts];  
int second = urlAsset.duration.value / urlAsset.duration.timescale;
```

and this code:

```
AVPlayerItem *playerItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithURL:_moviePath];
CMTime duration = playerItem.duration;
float seconds = CMTimeGetSeconds(duration);
NSLog(@"duration: %.2f", seconds);
```

they are all do not work

and xcode tips:

```
Error [IRForTarget]: Call to a symbol-only function 'memset' that is not present in the target
error: 0 errors parsing expression
error: The expression could not be prepared to run in the target
```

You can help me to get the video attributes?Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Now the following codes do working:

```
NSDictionary *opts = [NSDictionary 
    dictionaryWithObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO]
    forKey:AVURLAssetPreferPreciseDurationAndTimingKey];

AVURLAsset *urlAsset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:_moviePath options:opts];  
int second = urlAsset.duration.value / urlAsset.duration.timescale;
```

And I don't know Why it does not work before！

Comment: Did you managed to find the answer to this? i am struggling with this myself